# Understanding boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost

Why wouldn't the following compile:

```
void f(int8_t a)
{
}

void f(int16_t a)
{
}

typedef boost::variant<int8_t, int16_t> AttrValue;

int main()
{
    AttrValue a;
    a = int8_t(1);
    f(a);
}
```

With the compiler error:

```
error C2665: 'f' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
could be 'void f(int8_t)'
or 'void f(int16_t)'
```

However, this is OK:

```
std::cout << a; // f(a);
```

Where is Where is std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const AttrValue &) defined and why is it defined?

Comment: what is boost used for? what does it do? threading? gpu-programming?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık - http://www.boost.org/

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: boost is by far the best known C++ library outside the standard. www.boost.org

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Overload resolution happens at compile time, when your `boost::variant` instance could contain either type, so the compiler has no way of knowing whether to call `void f(int8_t)` or `void f(int16_t)`.

`std::cout << a` works because in either case it's calling the same function, [`std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const AttrValue &)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost/operator_id1820788.html), which inside dispatches on the runtime type of the instance.

You need to write a visitor to perform the dispatching:

```
struct f_visitor: public boost::static_visitor<void>
{
    template<typename T> void operator()(T t) const { return f(t); }
};

boost::apply_visitor(f_visitor(), a);
```

Comment: Where is std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const AttrValue &) defined?

Comment: @Baz it's defined by `boost::variant`.  I'll add the link to the documentation.

Comment: So an operator<< visitor is implemented by boost::variant? Is it added for the sake of convenience?

Comment: @Baz Yes, it would be possible to write yourself, but pretty much everyone wants to be able to stream out variant values.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Well, for one thing you are assigning `a` to itself. And since none of the overloads take a `boost::variant` type then of course the compiler can't find the correct function.</strike>

Also, you may have to use [`boost::get`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost/get_id1824090.html) to get value:

```
f(boost::get<int8_t>(a));
```

Comment: fixed assignment of a to itself in op.

Answer (score 0):

It happens that `operator<<` is defined for `boost::variant`, so the compiler does not need to perform any implicit type conversion. For your `f()` function, on the other hand, it does not know which conversion to select.